# recursive move command on windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to do a .bat copy of a .sh, I don't know much Windows cmd.
On Linux I could do

```
mv ...
```

or

```
rsync -a SOURCE/ DEST/ --remove-sent-files --ignore-existing --whole-file
```

but Windows "move" can't do the same

maybe there is a windows simple alternative, simpler and more performant than

```
for /R c:\sourceFolder\ %%G in (*) do ( move /Y "%%G" c:\destinationFolder\ )
```

Linux mv seems to update directories pointer, but the above Windows command will do hard stuff? I guess it's not a good idea for the big folders I need to frequently move

Comment: Use `robocopy`, included since Vista, or the older `xcopy` (which is capable, but requires more work adding switches to get it to work right).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `move` command can move directories as well as files.

```
cd /d C:\sourceFolder
rem move the files
for %%i in (*) do move "%%i" C:\destinationFolder
rem move the directories
for /d %%i in (*) do move "%%i" C:\destinationFolder
```

Comment: shouldn't this be for %i? (single %?)

Comment: @rationalboss You need %% if using a batch file, and the question explicitly said it was for a batch file. (Note that the original question also doubled the percent signs.)

Comment: ah, thank you! i was trying it directly through the command prompt and was wondering why it wasn't working. thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to use the folder path instead of (*)?

Comment: So `move * somewhere\` does move all files, but directories need to be moved one by one. Sigh...

Answer (score 18):

Robocopy did wonders for me:

```
 robocopy c:\cache c:\cache-2012 ?????-2012*.hash /S /MOV
```

I used it to move all files with certain mask out of `c:\cache` and its numerous subdirectories.

Comment: best answer for me (since it is part of recent windows versions)

Comment: The main problem with robocopy is it doesn't actually move files, but copy them and them delete the original ones. When moving files in the same drive, it's a big difference to be able to actually move the files (it's instant) instead of just copying them (it's a lot slower if you want to move big files). The main point of using the "move" command is it's really fast if moving files in the same drive, but unfortunately it doesn't move subdirectories when using wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but since it does not have a correct answer I figured I'd tie it off.

The old DOS command to accomplish this is:

```
   move <source directory> <destination directory>
```

So in the OP question:

```
   move C:\sourceFolder c:\destinationFolder
```

The folder and everything in the folder (including sub-directories) will be moved.

Comment: Just remember that `move` throws "access denied" if target folder exists

Answer (score 1):

XCOPY should do the trick, I use it it in batch files all the time

something like, if you're just trying to target .sh files

```
XCOPY /E /H /Y /C "%SOURCEDIR%\*.sh" "%TARGETDIR%"
```

Let me know if you have more questions

Comment: xcopy doesn't move files though, just copies them, so you need to delete everything in the source directory afterwards

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set DIR=
set OUTPUTDIR=C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Desktop\sandbox1\output
for /R %DIR% %%a in (*.jpg) do xcopy "%%a" "%OUTPUTDIR%"
```

Answer (score -2):

For recursive move in windows, a simple `move` command is ok. Here is the example, I think it would be helpful.

```
move D:\Dbbackup\*.dmp* D:\Dbbackup\year\month\
```

Where `.dmp` is the extension of the file that would be moved to the location recursive folder Dbbackup , then year, then month.

Comment: That's not a recursive move. Subdirectories will not be moved with that command. The move command doesn't support that, AFAIK.