# Move .txt files in different folders to a single folder using Batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, move

I'm trying to move all .txt files in different folders to a single folder using a batch file, I'm new to batch coding so I'm having some difficulties.

My code is as follows:

```
FOR /D /r %%G IN ("C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\PR\2016\08.2016\") DO MOVE  G\*.txt C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\PR\2016\
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursive move command on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155420/recursive-move-command-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

See the correct syntax of [For /r](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) or in an open cmd window type `help for`

```
@Echo off
For /r "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\PR\2016\08.2016\" %%G IN (*.txt
    ) Do echo Move "%%G" "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\PR\2016\"
Pause
```

If the output to screen looks OK remove the echo in front of the move command.

Comment: you were right my answer was not recursive. As for the "G*.txt" that's what he had in his question which is why I used that.

Comment: @RatherNotsay Well I guess that was his try to get the output of "%%G"

Comment: Yep, that is more obvious now that someone edited the question with proper code formatting.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this all in PowerShell. I am not sure it will work if you do not pass the $_.FullName which contains the path to the file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\PR\2016\08.2016\" -Filter *.txt | `
    ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } | `
    Move-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\PR\2016\"
```

Comment: No need to escape the line breaks, after the pipe or a comma powershell continues on the next line.

Comment: Yes, I know that the line continuation GRAVE ACCENT character is not required when there is a VERTICAL BAR at the end of the line. I was trying to be explicit  PowerShell is not a free-format language. There are times when it is needed.